# how to simulate mouse over without mouse events?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

In this question there are 7 submenus in the navbar, I want when the website is loaded, make something like hover over all the menus one by one. Do not trigger mouse events, only manipulate DOM/style, I must write the code in JavaScript

Here is one of the Submenus :

```html
<div class="submenu">
  <ul class="linkmenu">
    <li class="d-md-none">
      <div class="nav-item standalone-nav"><span><a href="/wines/_/N-n" data-nav-label="Browse all Offers"><strong>Browse all Offers</strong></a></span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="nav-item"> <span>Type</span> <i class="arrow down"></i>
      </div>
      . . . . .
      </a>
    </li> -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

css: [querySelecter]:hover

example:

```
.nav-item:hover { /* css code here */ }
```

js: a mouseover and mouseleave

example:

```
document.querySelecter('.nav-item').addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{ /* js */ }
document.querySelecter('.nav-item').addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{ /* js */ }
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, but what is required is not to use mouse event

Comment: Oh i didn't see that, sorry! 